# JFXPanel inside Swing component hangs application on JFXPanel construction (os x & JDK 1.8)

Tags: java, macos, swing, javafx, java-8

I'm running a JFXPanel inside a swing component (JPanel). The problem I'm having is that sometimes, not every time, the application hangs (freezes up) upon the creation of the JXFPanel. See code bellow.

```
public VideoPlayer(String url){
    if (MovieInfoConfig.DEBUG)
        System.out.println("1 Creating VideoPlayer Objct...");

    this.videoUrl = url;
    jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();

    if (MovieInfoConfig.DEBUG)
        System.out.println("2 JFXPanel object created...");

    createScene();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 560));
    add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

You can see my debug messages being printed. I will always reach the first step but as I said, on some occasions, the program hangs before it reaches the second debug message. In other words, the line `jfxPanel = new JFXPanel()` seems to be causing the problem.

I have only tested this on Mac OSX (Mavericks) JDK 1.8. To me it kind of feels like a JavaFX / OSX JDK 1.8 bug - but I haven't found anything about it online.

Does anyone have any clue? Is there any way for me to debug the JFXPanel constructor itself, to see what it going on just prior to the point when the application hangs?

Thank you all!

**EDIT 1** As suggested I made some changes to my main method. It however did not remove the problem. See below a full example that reproduces the problem:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.web.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BrowserTest extends JFrame {
    JPanel videoP = new JPanel();
    BrowserTest() {
        super("Test");
        System.out.println("Start BT");
        setSize(1200, 700);     
        setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        String[] videos = new String[3]; 
        videos[0] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/W-J2OYN9fF8?autoplay=true&controls=0";
        videos[1] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/8hP9D6kZseM?autoplay=true&controls=0";
        videos[2] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Rq9eM4ZXRgs?autoplay=true&controls=0";
        for(int x = 0; x < videos.length; x++) {
            JButton b = new JButton("Video " + x); 
            b.addActionListener(new bClick(videos[x])); 
            p1.add(b);
        }
        add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(videoP, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
                 new BrowserTest(); 
             }
         });
    }

    class bClick implements ActionListener {
        String url; 
        bClick(String url) {
            this.url = url; 
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (videoP.getComponents().length > 0) {    
                Component c = videoP.getComponent(0);
                if (c instanceof VideoPlayer)
                    ((VideoPlayer) c).stopTrailer(); 
            }
            videoP.removeAll();

            videoP.add(new VideoPlayer(url)); 
            System.out.println("Clicked url " + url); 
            videoP.revalidate();
            videoP.repaint();
        }
    }
}

class VideoPlayer extends JPanel {  
    private Stage stage;
    private WebView browser;
    private JFXPanel jfxPanel;
    private WebEngine webEngine;
    private String videoUrl;
    int xPos, yPos; 

    public VideoPlayer(String url){
        this.videoUrl = url;    
        System.out.println("1 Creating VideoPlayer Objct...");
        jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();  
        System.out.println("2 JFXPanel object created...");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 560));
        add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        createScene();
    }

    private void createScene() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("3 createScene run metod started");
                stage = new Stage();
                System.out.println("4 createScene - stage created");
                stage.setTitle("Video");
                stage.setResizable(true);
                Group root = new Group();
                Scene scene = new Scene(root,80,20);
                stage.setScene(scene);
                System.out.println("5 createScene Group and Scene created - also set the Scene");
                //Set up the embedded browser:
                browser = new WebView();
                System.out.println("6 createScene - WbView created");
                webEngine = browser.getEngine();
                webEngine.load(videoUrl);
                System.out.println("7 createScene - Loeaded the video URL: " + videoUrl);
                ObservableList<Node> children = root.getChildren();
                children.add(browser);                     
                jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
                System.out.println("8 createScene - set the scene on the jfxPanel");
            }
        });
    }

    public void stopTrailer() { 
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(":: stopTrailer() called");
                remove(jfxPanel);
                webEngine.load(null);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Did you got any solution for this ?

Comment: No - sadly not. But I'm guessing this is also a OS specific problem... I'm running on OSX. You?

Comment: I found a solution, I am providing it in answer.

Comment: From a JavaFX Thread, you open a new JFame? Have you tried to wrap your method that runs swing code inside `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same problem was coming in my OSX. When running from eclipse it was running file as soon as I create a installer(.app) for the jar and it hangs. So I found a way out, while creating the .app for the OSX in the Info.plist file I increased the minimum and maximum memory. Which fixed the issue and now it is running smooth. Not sure if this will fix your issue but just thought of sharing it with you.

Thanks !

Comment: I'd like to mark this as a correct answer, but since I don't run this as an app but simply by executing java it's hard for me to replicate. If there's no way to increase the memory limits for java in general (which sounds really weird for what I know about applications running in modern operating systems) I might try that..?

Comment: Are you running as a jar file ? If yes you can not set max memory in jar file. You need an wrapper like an app file to run the jar and in the wrapper you can mention the max heap.

Comment: Ok. I'll mark this as answered, in lack of better explanation for the problem. A lack of memory is a likely reason after all. Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem and this solution did not work for me. I think the problem has to do with the fact that JavaFX is running on the same thread as Swing on the mac.

Comment: @EmilyCrutcher : Ok. I am not very sure if "Platform.runLater(new Runnable()" creates a new Thread or not. It probably is not the Swing thread. But not sure.

Comment: On Windows and Linux it's a separate thread running the JavaFX  event thread, on mac the situation is more complicated due to the  mac architecture.

Answer (score 2):

In the stopTrailer method, while running within the JavaFX thread, the JavaFx panel is removed from its swing container.

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            ...
            remove(jfxPanel); 
            webEngine.load(null);
        }
    });
```

In similar code, I also had incorrectly added the JFXPanel on the JavaFX thread and had the same hang on mac. When I found and removed the bad add, the code stopped hanging.

I believe what is happening is that on Windows and Linux, as the AWT and JavaFX threads are completely distinct, the code while bad, does not cause disaster. However, on mac, where the underlying UI events must take place on the same native OS thread,  removing or adding the jfxPanel from the JavaFx thread  almost certainly causes AWT/Swing and JavaFX to end up deadlocking on those UI resources.